Spring boot app running local Consul Check fails in docker
Hi All and thanks in advance.
I am running a Consul in a docker container. The docker compose can not be more easy:
version: '3.1'
services:
  consul:
    image: hashicorp/consul:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: consul
    ports:
      - "8400:8400"
      - "8500:8500"
      - "8600:8600"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

This will run within a docker contianer but then I am running a spring boot app with spring cloud consul.
This is the configuration in bootstrap.yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: Gateway
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
      discovery:
        service-name: ${spring.application.name}
        hostname: host.docker.internal
        health-check-path: /actuator/health
        instance-id: ${spring.application.name}-1
        health-check-interval: 10s

The main problem is that when checking in consul the service registration

I think the issue is due to because consul is running on docker, can not resolve properly the host to check the health of the service, like setting in the configuration to register the service host as "localhost" and "host.docker.internal" or adding extra_host in the docker compose. I tried different things but any of them has work.
I also tried to run the docker compose with network mode Host to bind my host interface to the container interface but doesnt even work.
From the container I am also getting this:

so it looks like that from inside the container I can not reach this host. I tried also with fixed Ips like 127.0.0.1 and only the direct interface network was the one that worked


spring:
  application:
    name: Gateway
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
      discovery:
        ip-address: 172.24.128.1
        service-name: ${spring.application.name}
        hostname: 172.24.128.1
        health-check-path: /actuator/health
        instance-id: ${spring.application.name}-1
        health-check-interval: 10s

but I would like to have a better solution
Tons of thanks in advance
